# Using values from Lookup (Count)

Tags: 2013

I am struggling to use a value from another list. I have a lookup to a count related on a custom list to determine the number of projects per client. To be able to create a unique project number for each new project, I am trying to use that count related with a workflow to do something simple like the (count related)+1 = NextProjectNumber. I have everything else figured out except how to extract that value from the Count related.

I have tried workflows to copy to a text field, number, integer, ... but nothing works. If I change my workflows to reference a field which has a value of 5 (for example) they are working perfectly but it just copying that Count Related field which I am struggling with.

I am a bit of a sharepoint novice so I may be doing things completely wrong.

My WF is something along the lines of

Set Variable 1 to Current List:Projects(Count Related)
Do calculation variable 1 + 1 (set as:variable 2)
Set Current List:Next Project Number to Variable 2.

Any assistance would appreciated.

Comment: why don't u use calculation column to update project number.

Comment: The project number needs to be dependent on a customer. The count is count related of projects is currently by customer and I need to create a unique project number along the lines of customer1-1, customer1-2, customer1-3, customer2-1... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 lists: **Clients** list with fields `Title` (text) and `Project Count` (number); and **Projects** with fields `Title` (text), `Client` (lookup to Client list), and `ProjectNumber` (text). Run the following workflow on the Projects list when item is created:

[image]

1. `Do Calcuation` action. `Clients:Project Count` looks up from clients where `Title` equals `Client` returned as `Lookup Value (as Text)`.
2. `Current Item: Client (as Lookup Value)`-`variable:nextProject`
3. `Update List Item (Current Item)` action where `Title` = `Current Item: Client (as Lookup Value)`

[image]